# Build static library with asset_manager using NDK r10e

Tags: android-ndk, android-assets

I am building a static library that uses `AAssetManager` (`#include <android/asset_manager.h>`)  in C++ and then  I will use the library from java.

The thing is I can't include `libandroid` because I can't use `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid` when building static library.(`local_ldlibs` is always ignored for static libraries)

So how can build my static library without using `local_ldlibs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a static library, you don't need to satisfy the external references, but if somebody uses your library, they must link `libandroid.so`. You can put this in documentation of your library.

If you provide an **Android.mk** with it, you can set `LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS = -landroid`. BTW, you can also set `LOCAL_EXPORT_INCLUDES` to the directory with public headers for your library.

At any rate, NDK 10 is obsolete. I strongly recommend to move to the current release (unless you desperately need support for **android-3**).

Comment: Pretty sure I added `LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS` in r13/r14. So, yeah, update your NDK.

Comment: My problem was I didn't specify the APP_PLATFORM so it was set to android-3 by default (maybe because I am using NDK 10). After setting APP_PLATFORM to android-9, the problem went away.

Comment: @DanAlbert: `EXPORT_LDLIBS` appears in r10e. I did not check the full history.

Comment: I must be thinking of `EXPORT_LDFLAGS` or something.